PowerShell output log showing incorrect information
I'm currently modifying a script written by a previous employee, and the main purpose of the script is to restart some servers. Currently, the portion of the script that actually goes through the restarts looks like this:
#For privacy reasons, the actual file path is replaced with "File Path"
Clear-Host
       $YN = Read-Host -Prompt "CONFIRM REBOOT [Y/N]"

       if(($YN -eq "Y") -or ($YN -eq "y"))
       {
           Get-ChildItem -Path "\\File Path\Server Restarts\Logs\Restart Logs" -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination "\\File Path\Server Restarts\Logs\Restart Logs\Archive" -Force

           $ScriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
           $Log = New-Item "\\File Path\Server Restarts\Logs\Restart Logs\$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss) Restarts.txt" -ItemType File -Force
           $Date = Get-Date -Format "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"
           $Now = [datetime]::Now

           Clear-Host
           Write-Host `n `n `n
           Write-Host "Rebooting all servers and verifying reboot status..." `n `n
           Write-Host "Please standby, process may take up to 30 minutes..." `n `n

           #Below, $Servers is declared elsewhere, pointing to a .txt file with a list of server names
           Restart-Computer -ComputerName $Servers -Wait -For PowerShell -Delay 2 -Force -Timeout 1800

           "----------------------------------Script executed on $Date----------------------------------" + "`r`n" | Out-File $Log -Append

           foreach($Server in $Servers)
           {
               $LastBoot = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server -EA 0).LastBootUpTime
               $PingRequest = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 1 -Quiet

               if(($PingRequest -eq $true) -and ($LastBoot -gt $Now))
               {
                   Add-Content -Path $Log -Value "$Server`: Reboot Successful."
               }
               elseif ($PingRequest -eq $false)
               {
                   Add-Content -Path $Log -Value "$Server`: Server not detected, please confirm"
               }
               else
               {
                   Add-Content -Path $Log -Value "$Server`: Restart not detected, please restart server manually"
               }
           }

           Clear-Host
           Write-Host `n `n `n
           Write-Host "All done!" `n
           Write-Host "Please review logs, as script may have run into problems." `n `n
           Log-Location
           Pause
       }
       else
       {
           Clear-Host
           Write-Host `n `n `n
           Write-Host "Server Reboots Aborted." `n `n
           Pause
       }

Currently, upon confirmation from user, it will take the log from the previous restarts and move that into an archive folder. After moving the previous log, it will create a new log in it's place, and figure out the current time ($Now). After that, it restarts the servers, then pings them, comparing last boot up time to $Now, and puts the results in the log.
When recently running the script, I kept pinging the first server on the list with command prompt to see if it was working in real time. As the script ran, I was able to ping it, then I wasn't able to ping it for a moment, then I was able to ping it again, so I know that at least first server restarted. However, when I checked the log after the script timed-out, not only did it display only 5 servers out of 13 total, it said "Restart not detected, please restart server manually" for all five it logged, including the one I tracked.
Based on my understanding, the script should be restarting all the servers (which it appears to be doing) and once it's done doing that, compare the boot time to $Now (which boot time should be greater than $Now) and ping each server. The things I'm not understanding are as follows:

Why didn't the first server get logged as "Reboot Successful" when I know for certain the server was restarted?

Why is the output log only displaying 5 of the 13 servers and not all 13?
Is there something obvious I'm missing here, or do I need to heavily rework this portion of the script?



Try logging the value of $LastBoot and verify the output - if this contains an unexpected value (e.g. $null if your -EA 0 swallows an exception) your first if branch might not be triggering, which means you’ll run the 3rd branch instead and write “restart not detected” to the log…

Most likely $LastBoot = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server -EA 0).LastBootUpTime doesn't return anything (knowing that you ignoring any errors). I would add the $LastBoot to your log.
